# Javascript Date utcoffset and adding minutes

Tags: javascript, date, timezone

What am I doing wrong here ?
I cannot get this to matchup with the current UTC time, after I enter my current time as userPickedTime.

```
userPickedTime = new Date();
userPickedTime.setHours(3,30,0);
userTimeChoiceConvertedToUtc  = new Date (userPickedTime.getTime() + 
    (3600000*userPickedTime.getTimezoneOffset()));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Raul is correct that the offset is expressed in minutes and you are using the wrong multiplier, you really *shouldn't* add the offset to the timestamp.  The result will be a different point in time entirely.

The timestamp is *already* in terms of UTC, and the `Date` object constructor expects that you are passing in milliseconds from the epoch, also in terms of UTC.

You should just use the `getUTC...` functions, or the `toUTCString`, or `toISOString` functions instead.

If you desire more specific formatting of UTC values, consider using the [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) library.

Comment: What do you mean it points to a different point in time entirely ? Thank you for your time.

Comment: A `Date` object wraps a numeric timestamp, which is the number of milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970 UTC.  It's *always* in UTC.  So if you add a number to it, you are representing a *different* point in time on the UTC timeline.  The `Date` object you create will still be associated with the local time zone, just at the shifted point in time.  This will cause incorrect results when you get near a Daylight Saving Time transition.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining. I had to reread it a few times to get it. Would it be too much to ask how you would write it ? I dont get how toUTCString or toISOString can be used to arrive at the result.

Comment: I am marking this as correct, as I hope me and Raul learned something new.

Comment: Well, what is the result you desire?  In your question, you just end up with a `Date` object.  In other words, what do you then *do* with the date object?  If you want it output as string in UTC, what format do you need it in?  Or are you passing it to something else, and if so - what?

Comment: I would want the user to enter at time choice, convert it to utc after  accounting for the local timezone utc offset. I would then later use this as a string format and use it server side.

Comment: Ok, so when you're passing the date from the client back to the server, that's when you use `.toISOString()`, which generates an ISO8601 string *in UTC* to send back to your server.  You don't need any other conversions.

Answer (score 1):

The [timezoneOffset](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettimezoneoffset.asp) is in minutes, you shoul ddo:

```
userTimeChoiceConvertedToUtc  = new Date (userPickedTime.getTime() + 
(userPickedTime.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000));
```